# difference between window and document in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wanna know whats the difference between **document** && **window** in jQuery ??

These two are used quite often, but i hv never got the difference between them.

Comment: Think of the document as being *inside* the window. The window is where all of the page's global properties reside.

Comment: Your question should be "i wanna know whats the difference between document && window in JavaScript ??“, as both objects come from vanilla JS, not jQuery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Phew . . . that's actually a lot bigger of a question than you may realize.   :)

The **Extremely Short Answer** is . . .

The `window` object represents the container that the `document` object is displayed in.  In fact, when you reference `document` in your code, you are really referencing `window.document` (all properties and methods of `window` are global and, as such, can be referenced without actually specifying `window` at the beginning . . . e.g., `document` = `window.document` and `alert()` = `window.alert()`).

The `document` object is the currently loaded DOM document . . . so, if you go to http://www.stackoverflow.com, the `document` object would be all of the HTML, JS, CSS, etc. that are loaded to make up the StackOverflow home page.  If you click on the link to this question, the `document` is now all of the same kinds of assets that make up the page for this question.  When you change `documents` though, you are still in the same `window` (though some of the properties of the `window` have changed).

For LOTS of information on the two objects (including standard properties and methods), check out these links:

- the `window` object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window
- the `document` object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document

**One last note:** While not completely accurate, if you are a visual person, you can think of the `window` as the browser window or tab that you have open to view web pages . . . you may move through many `document`s as you are surfing, but, if you never change to a different tab, you are always in the same `window`.

Answer (score 3):

This article explain benefits of both

http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

In short term: 
`window` - you can handle if user interact with window (open, close, etc..)
`document` - is a content of window and you can handle if user iteract with content (watched, fired some events like a click, change etc)

> But keep in mind !! They are different objects and does different
>   things.

Answer (score 2):

The window is the first thing that gets loaded into the browser. 
This window object has the majority of the properties like length, innerWidth, innerHeight, name, if it has been closed, its parents, and more.
What about the document object then?

The document object is your html, aspx, php, or other document that will be loaded into the browser. The document actually gets loaded inside the window object and has properties available to it like title, URL, cookie, etc. What does this really mean? That means if you want to access a property for the window it is window.property, if it is document it is window.document.property which is also available in short as document.property.

For More detail with screenshot read following article

http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/