# window.load and document.ready still waiting for DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case, I need to check the height of images (100% width).

```
  $(window).load(function() {    
    var heightImage = $('ul.images li[style*="display: list-item"] img').height();
    $(window).resize(function() {
      var heightImage = $('ul.images li[style*="display: list-item"] img').height();
      $('ul.images').css("height", heightImage + "px");
    }).resize();
  });
```

With that method of `.load` function, it waits for all contents ready loaded after finally it check the height of the images.

If i use

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
```

It doesn't check the images height. The weird is when I inspect element, suddenly it loads `.ready` function and gives me the height of the image. As if, the `.ready` function, in my case, only works when there is activity in the web, such as when I inspect the element.

How to solve this.

Can anybody help, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: document ready does not wait for the images to load. Window load executes when images are loaded. What is the issue? Load is the correct event to use when you need to wait for the height of the images.

Comment: but in my case it does. It only works when there is activity in the web or in the browser; such as when suddenly I inspect element, document ready is working.

Comment: check my post to understand .load and .ready http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080362/difference-between-window-and-document-in-jquery/30080748#30080748

Comment: @daremachine _document - is a content of window and you can handle if user iteract with content (watched, fired some events like a click, change etc)_

Comment: The issue  is `I want it to be loaded as soon as the page is loaded without have to wait for some event you listed there`

Comment: The problem with load is it waits for all contents ready to be loaded.

Comment: but images are contents not a functions .. dom ready is executed after window load ... i don't understand your problem properly

Comment: *"The problem with load is it waits for all contents ready to be loaded."* That is how window load works. If you want to wait until the one image is loaded, than add an onload event to that image!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$('ul.images li[style*="display: list-item"] img').load(function() {
  var heightImage = $(this).height();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var heightImage = $('ul.images li[style*="display: list-item"] img').height();
    $('ul.images').css("height", heightImage + "px");
  }).resize();
});
```